# Steam won't stop muting my music and/or skype conversations on lobby join

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

Every time I join a lobby in CS: GO, Steam mutes everything except the game on my computer.

How to stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on your volume icon in the taskbar (or open it through control panel) and then select Playback Devices. Then go to the Communications tab and set it to "Do nothing." Should be all set.